# Microsoft RPC and Thrift

Tags: rpc, thrift

Is Microsoft RPC
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374169%28VS.85%29.aspx 
same as Thrift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [Apache Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) also allows you to build RPC clients and servers, but it's more than just a Windows thing. Thrift was originally developed at Facebook.

Comment: MS rpc also allow making client http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378705%28VS.85%29.aspx and server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378869%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @userbb Yeah, that is the respect they are similar in... Apart from that, though, they are not the same thing.